# DBMS_OUTPUT - Printing text without printing a full line

Tags: plsql

Is there any way to print text without printing an entire line of text in Oracle PL/SQL? Currently, I am only aware of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(text)`. Is there an equivalent in Oracle PL/SQL to Java's `System.out.print(text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are seeking for:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(text);
```

From [DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-1BCA24ED-0799-4ACA-9FB1-4CEC24FE41E7):

> This procedure places a partial line in the buffer.
>
> *Usage Notes:*
>
> **You can build a line of information piece by piece by making multiple calls to PUT,** or place an entire line of information into the buffer by calling PUT_LINE.